# How to secure CRTP against providing wrong superclass?

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp, static-assert

In the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), we write

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
};
```

What would be a good way to make the code robust another copy-paste omissions, so that the following snippet throws a compile-time error:

```
class AnotherDerived : public Base<Derived> {
};
```

I'm using Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Give `Base` a private dtor and then make `Derived` a friend?

Comment: Maybe the constructor Base(Derived&)  {} - but that is close to being paranoid.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Thought about that, but this messes up the interface, too...

Comment: @T.C.: Nice idea -- but is this possible without giving `Derived` access to other private members of `Base`?

Comment: @krlmlr: You can add another inheritance layer to hold the members that need to remain private.  Using composition should also be possible.  (Remember friendship is not transitive)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks a lot, a second inheritance layer did the trick for me.

Comment: The 'duplicate' answer is pre-C++11 and hence not appropriate. I vote for re-opening. Moreorver, the answers given are not fully satisfactory.

Comment: @Walter: Can you suggest a better solution using C++11 features?

Comment: @krlmlr No, but perhaps somebody else can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `Base`'s destructor private, and then make `Derived` a friend of `Base<Derived>`:

```
template <class Derived>
class Base {
    private: ~Base() = default;
    friend Derived;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
};
```

This does not actually make doing

```
class AnotherDerived : public Base<Derived> {
};
```

illegal, but any attempt to actually construct an `AnotherDerived` will fail.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me -- I now have a class `BaseImp` from which `Base` inherits in order to avoid exposing private members to the pseudo-friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can `static_assert` that the argument derives from `Base<Argument>`, but that's as far as you can go.

Comment: Where would you do that? Inside the base class as a member-declaration, that information might not be available (yet) -- in fact, the Standard requires the second argument of `is_base_of` is a complete type. Inside a member function, an instantiation of that member function might be required to actually perform the check.

Comment: @dyp: Would the check always be done if performed in the constructor of `Base`?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with static assertions -- could you please give an example?

Comment: @krlmlr As far as I know, a `static_assert` inside a constructor of `Base` is only checked if that constructor is instantiated (e.g. if it is called). Although the error message might be better, I think the requirements for the `static_assert` check to be performed are higher than the check T.C. proposed.