# Cast empty base class pointer to child class pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I've got some code that uses a somewhat sneaky cast from a base class type to a child class type, where the child class type is specified as a template parameter. I'm assuming since the base class declares no data members and is zero-sized, the base class pointer address will be the same as the child, and the cast will succeed. So far the code runs correctly.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
template <class RangeT>
struct CppIterator {
    CppIterator(const RangeT& range) { ... }
    // ... methods calling RangeT's members
};

// Base class, provides begin() / end() methods. 
template<class RangeT>
struct CppIterableBase {
    CppIterator<RangeT> begin() { 
        return CppIterator<RangeT>( *(RangeT*)this );  // Is this safe?
    }
    CppIterator<RangeT> end() { ... }
};

struct MyRange : CppIterableBase<MyRange> {
    // ... 
};
```

My question is basically - is the code kosher? Will a base pointer always equate to a child pointer if the base is empty? Is it implementation-dependent? Will I run into trouble later on?

It solves my problem nicely but I'm a little dubious.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need this?

Comment: I have a variety of range types - inheriting prevents me from needing to define the same begin() and end() methods over and over again.

Comment: I meant why you need to cast it, not why you need an iterator class with template type.

Comment: The name for this pattern is CRTP. Use a `static_cast`, not the C-style cast, which can degenerate into a dangerous `reinterpret_cast` if you mess up the inheritance.

Comment: @MatsPetersson CppIterator accesses members in MyRange, not CppIterableBase, so I think the type passed into its constructor needs to be MyRange (compilation fails without the cast, although the error messages are crpytic).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks - looks like it's indeed the CRTP - I've run into it with Boost and metaprogramming a bit without reading up on it further. Good to know it's an established pattern. static_cast worked here, though I think I need to research a bit to understand how it's different.

Comment: note: you can write `static_cast<RangeT &>(*this)` , rather than casting to pointer and dereferencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the base class to be empty.

As long as the base is accessible, unambiguous, and non-virtual, and the pointer-to-base actually points to the base subobject of a derived object, it is valid to perform a `static_cast` from a pointer-to-base to pointer-to-derived. The compiler will perform any adjustment necessary to the pointer value.

What you are doing is actually a common pattern, called the curiously recurring template pattern (or CRTP).

`reinterpret_cast` is a completely different beast, however, and in this case would probably be a one-way ticket to undefined behavior land (I'm too lazy to dig into the standard and figure out under which corner cases it isn't UB). And since a C-style cast can become a `reinterpret_cast` (here, if you accidentally derive `Foo` from `Base<Baz>` when `Baz` doesn't derive from `Base<Baz>`), it should not be used.

Additionally, there are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548958/how-to-secure-crtp-against-providing-wrong-superclass) to ensure that you don't accidentally derive `Foo` from `Base<Bar>` - which simply using `static_cast` will not prevent if `Bar` also derives from `Base<Bar>`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the CRTP.

Using `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` is safer, as C-style casts will in some cases be "too strong".

Using `Foo<>` for thr CRTP base class:

So long as the `Foo<Derived>` in question is actually a base of `Derived`, then a `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` is safe at runtime and does the right thing.

A `static_assert` of `is_base_of` can reduce one source of possible error here, but not all.  If `struct Bar : Foo<Derived>` the above cast does undefined behaviour, and I know of no way to check for that error.

Comment: You can't check at the point of the `static_cast`, but it is possible to ensure that creating a `Bar` object doesn't compile (for some definition of "ensure").