# Securing CRTP: is private destructor the only solution?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, crtp, static-assert

How to avoid

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base { int foo() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar(); } };

struct derived : base<derived> { int bar(); };        
struct another_derived : base<derived> { int bar(); };  // error: wrong base
```

*without additional code in derived classes*?

This has been asked [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548958/how-to-secure-crtp-against-providing-wrong-superclass) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417782/how-to-avoid-errors-while-using-crtp) (though without the extra condition of avoiding additional code in derived classes), with the recommended [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7240019/1023390)

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base {
  int foo() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar(); } 
private:
  ~base() {}
  friend Derived;
};
```

However, this not only secures against above error, but also makes all private members of `Base` accessible from `Derived`. Is there an alternative, which avoids that? Or can it be conclusively shown that this is impossible?

---

**edit**

I actually have a more complex problem, where in addition to usual usage (as above) there is also

```
template<typename Derived>
struct intermediate : base<Derived>
{
  int bar() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->ark(); }
};
```

when the private destructor trick fails (since `intermediate` is not befriended by `base`).

Comment: Read the answer below the "recommended answer" you linked. This solve the problem, not in the ideal way, but at first sight it seems like way better than the private dtor + friendship.

Comment: @Melkon I have seen that answer, but it comes with additional code in the derived classes, which I wanted to avoid if possible. But it may be the only viable solution (see my edit).

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_base_of<base<Derived>, Derived>::value, "");`http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: @zahir that does not work here, consider the example: `base<derived>` itself is perfectly okay, it's just the wrong base class.

Comment: @Walter: I know it's not ideal, but it's forced to the programmer who write Derived. He just can't forget to do it. I don't think an ideal solution is exist, since Base class know nothing about who derives from it, i think only Derived can check it. :(